# ngClass used with ngFor in Angular to toggle icons

Tags: javascript, angular, binding, ngfor, ng-class

I have this piece of code from component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let passenger of passengers; let i=index">
  {{ passengers[i].child ? 'Child' : "" }}
  Name: {{ passengers[i].name }}
  Seat: {{ seats[i]}}
  Extra luggage: {{ passengers[i].luggage ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
</div>
```

Instead of having Yes or No for the luggage part, which is depending on the user choice, I would like to show icon (suitcase if luggage = true, and strikethrough icon if luggage = false)

I was thinking about doing this with `ngClass` but I'm not sure how to properly do it due to the fact that those divs are iterated via `ngFor` and their number depends on user's choice as well.

```
<div [ngClass]="['greenIcon', 'redIcon']">Luggage</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what icon method/library you're using but

You should be able to use [ngClass] and simplify it to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let passenger of passengers; let i = index">
    {{ passenger.child ? 'Child' : "" }}
    Name: {{ passenger.name }}
    Seat: {{ seats[i]}}
    Extra luggage: 
    <div [ngClass]="{'greenIcon': passenger.luggage, 'redIcon': !passenger.luggage}">
        {{ passenger.luggage ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
    </div>
</div>
```

[ngClass] can be used as a dictionary with the classes being the keys and a boolean for the value to determine if it should be applied. [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
[ngClass]="{ 'class-name': true }"
```